# Find date value in a column VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date

[data on my Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMel1.jpg)I would like to finde a date in column A. This is the date formát: "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss". It always find nothing, but the date what I am searching for is in the column A.
This is a snippet of my code:

```
Dim LastDay As Date
Dim strdate As String
Dim rCell As Range

strdate = Format(LastDay, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss")

Set rCell = Cells.Find(What:=CDate(strdate), After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues _
        , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

If rCell Is Nothing Then
MsgBox ("nothing")
Else
```

**EDIT:** New code per comments.

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim LastDayRow As Long
    Dim FirstDayRow As Long
    Dim LastDay As Date
    Dim FirstDay As Date
    Dim rcell As Range

    LastDayRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("E" & LastDayRow).Copy Range("G1")
    FirstDayRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & FirstDayRow).Copy Range("G2")
    LastDay = Cells(LastDayRow, "E").Value
    FirstDay = Cells(FirstDayRow, "A").Value

    Set rcell = Cells.Find(What:=LastDay, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
                , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If rcell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("nothing")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: From the code you provide, it doesn't appear that you set any value to your `LastDay` variable.

Comment: The code u written is find base on xlValue. The date store in cells actually is just number. Therefore you will not able to find it using LookIn:=xlValue

Comment: It could also be that the format( converts the date to a string format; and you're looking for a date

Comment: I recommend you try using LookIn:=XlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the formát of the date. The "/" in this date format: yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss confused the vba run.
These code lines in the source file solved the problem:

```
Sheet1.Range("A:A").Replace What:="/", Replacement:="."
Sheet1.Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss"
Sheet3.Range("E:E").Replace What:="/", Replacement:="."
Sheet3.Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss"
```

Answer (score 1):

Date types are stored in both Excel and VBA as Doubles.  Search for the double value instead of the date by changing the LookIn parameter to `xlFormulas`. You can also omit the MatchCase parameter (you're using the default).

```
Set rCell = Cells.Find(What:=LastDay, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas _
        , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
```

Note that you are doing some meaningless work here...

```
strdate = Format(LastDay, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss")
```

...because you simply cast it ***back*** to a Date when you do your Find:

```
What:=CDate(strdate)
```

Comment: I changed what you recommended but still doesn't find the date in the column A. If I set LastDay as Double, the macro stops with error message.

Comment: @vergab - Your updated code runs perfectly fine for me.  What error are you getting and where?

Comment: rcell value is "nothing" but the date is in the column A. This is the last date in column E: 2016/08/02 18:16:21 and it is in column A as well.

Comment: @vergab - I can't replicate that behavior. When I run your updated code it sets `rcell` to `$G$1` as expected.

Comment: Did it find the date when you let run the code? Did rcell have any other value then nothing?

Comment: @vergab - It found it in `$G$1`.  I took that to be the point of copying it there with `Range("E" & LastDayRow).Copy Range("G1")`.

Comment: But why appears the message box with "nothing"? It should find it in column A because my excel sheet contains the same date in column A and column E as well. Copying value in G1 and G2 already worked properly from the begining.

Comment: @vergab - You'll need to add a screen-shot of your data to your question. I can't replicate the issue you're having without seeing the data.

Comment: I attached the screenshot of my excel sheet. I marked with yellow the date values in column A and E. It shouldn't been shown the message box because it should find the date in column A.

Comment: @vergab - I still can't replicate with a duplicate of your data.  Are the values stored as strings on the worksheet?  It might be a localization issue.

Comment: Yes, these values are strings on the workseet. But you can handle it as a date. This worksheet is converted from a xml file.

Comment: @vergab - Does this return 'True'?  `Debug.Print IsDate("2016/08/02 18:16:21")`  What about `Debug.Print IsDate(Cells(LastDayRow, "E").Value)`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this "Debug.Print" issue. What is this?

Comment: @vergab - Hit Ctrl-G.  That should open the Immediate Window.  Type in `?IsDate("2016/08/02 18:16:21")` and hit [Enter].  What does it display?

Comment: Both of them are "True"