# Why is my VBA .Find not finding anything?

Tags: vba, excel

I have what I thought was a pretty simple `.Find`, but it isn't working.

```
lngLastRow = wsFound.Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Set SearchRange = wsFound.Range("D1:D" & lngLastRow)
For Each a In wsFound.Range(wsFound.Range("D2"), wsFound.Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
    With SearchRange
        Set c = .Find("01/03/1950", LookIn:=xlValues) 'a.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Firstfind = a.Address
            Do
                wsFound.Range("A" & a.Row & ":U" & a.Row).Copy
                LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Duplicates").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Duplicates").Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                If c Is Nothing Then
                    GoTo DoneFinding
                End If
            Loop While a.Address <> Firstfind
        End If
```

DoneFinding:
        End With
    Next a

I'm pretty sure that I've got this correct I used info from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get it this far.

But it isn't finding anything!

My data looks like this:

```
+--------------+---------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
|     A        |    B    |     C     |       D       |       E      |
+--------------+---------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
| Staff Number | Surname | Forenames | Date of Birth |  Address 1   |
+--------------+---------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
|   1000064036 | Farrell | Margaret  | 01/03/1950    | 11 The Close |
|   1000064036 | Farrell | Margaret  | 01/03/1950    | 11 The Close |
|   1000064036 | Farrell | Margaret  | 01/03/1950    | 11 The Close |
+--------------+---------+-----------+---------------+--------------+
```

So I know that there are 3 duplicates in the DOB `D` column that should be found.

Comment: I haven't grokked the whole thing, but if you're looking in D for "01/31/1950", you're not going to find it.  They're all 01/03/1950...or am I missing something?

Comment: Also, NB that I don't think you will find a date value using a string literal, you need to be looking for a date value, not a string.

Comment: @Hrothgar totally right. I have the wrong date in there. After updating it to the correct date *01/03/1950* then it finds them. But If I use the `a.Value` it does not because `a.Value` = *1/3/1950*.

Comment: @DavidZemens I'm not sure what the difference is, but I'll see if I can figure it out and make a change.

Comment: does the cell contain text which looks like a date, or does it contain an actual date value (which is actually a long numeric, formatted as a date)? look. at other questions here on the topic of using Find with date values might offer some info for you.

Comment: @DavidZemens It does contain a date. The date is entered as *1/3/1950*, but shows as *01/03/1950*. I'll see about finding other questions using .Find on a date.

Comment: instead of `.Find("01/03/1950",` try this: `.Find(#01/03/1950#,...`

Comment: @DavidZemens searching for `01/03/1950` works fine. It's when I search for `a.Value` which = `1/3/1950` that it doesn't find anything.

Comment: try either `Cdate(a.Value)` or `Cstr(Format(a.Value, "m/d/yyyy"))`

Comment: I finally found it in a comment on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852887/find-date-value-in-a-column-vba.  I had to change the `LookIn` to `xlFormulas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out through some more searching as per a comment from David Zemens on making my search more specific.

Here is what worked:

```
For Each a In wsFound.Range(wsFound.Range("D2"), wsFound.Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
    With SearchRange
        Set c = SearchRange.Find(a.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Firstfind = a.Address
            Do
                wsFound.Range("A" & a.Row & ":U" & a.Row).Copy
                LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Duplicates").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Duplicates").Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                If c Is Nothing Then
                    GoTo DoneFinding
                End If
            Loop While a.Address <> Firstfind
        End If
DoneFinding:
    End With
Next a
```

I had to change the `LookIn` value from `xlValues` to `xlformulas` and now it is finding the dates that I'm looking for even without using `CDate`.

I found this in a comment from another question. [Find date value in a column VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852887/find-date-value-in-a-column-vba), the comment was by Eric K