# Find a cell containing a specific date

Tags: excel, vba, date, find

I have a excel serving as timeline record. Column B contains date of a year, and columns right on it record various event.

I want to make a button which can jump to the row of current date. The first thing I try to do is find a cell with specific date in it. I get a date from a existing cell in column B, then turn back to find it. However the `Find` method returns nothing.

```
Sub gotoToday()

Dim LDate As Date
Dim dateCol As Range
Dim cell As Range

LDate = Range("b197").Value ' do get a valid date value here

Set dataCol = Range("B2:B365") ' b197 is inside the range

dataCol.Select

Set cell = Selection.Find(what:=LDate, after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    Lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

cell.Select ' cell get Nothing here

End Sub
```

Basically I am following [This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852887/find-date-value-in-a-column-vba). Not sure what thing I am missing, can any one help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are looking for a Date type (`Dim LDate As Date`) whereas `dataCol` contains strings. Try looking for a string:

```
Dim LDate As String
'...
LDate = Range("b197").Text
'...
```

**EDIT**

You can get a string from a date, formatted to your liking, by using the [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function. Example:

```
LDate = Format(Range("b197").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

If your values in column B really are dates, computed using formulas and formatted as mm/dd, the `Find` will work with LDate as a string and `LookIn:=xlValues`, even if they are displayed without the year.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I generate column in the following way, manually type "1/1/2020" in B3, use `=B3+1` in B4 and copy the formula on all following cells. I just try search for the initial cell "B3" instead of "B197", this time `Find` returns the correct cell content. Seems B4 and the following cells don't record a raw date format

Comment: Ah! Then you should be looking in xlValues, not xlFormulas. Your formulas do not contain dates.

Comment: Use `Range().Text` do solve the problem, but there is one limitation : it only returns "mm/dd" per my excel settings. In the future I will use `Dim LDate As String   LDate = Date `, which will gives a "mm/dd/yyyy" format, the search will fail. I can do string manipulation to get "mm/dd" from `Date`, but it will lose the year information, if my timesheet have more than one year, it will return multiple matches. In case I don't want to change formatting options in column B from "mm/dd" to "mm/dd/yyyy", is it possible to still keep the year information in xlVlaue?